# Call to a member function get_id() on array in... returns Fatal Error

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, report, fatal-error

I know this is a bit specific, but I'm tearing my hair out over this after lots of (confusing) reading online!

**I've somehow broken my Woocommerce install's Stock report**, and can't seem to undo it (I tried disabling all plugins and PHP functions but nothing seemed to work)...**is there a way I can replace the broken file with a fresh copy without messing up my whole (live ecommerce) site?** I'm only a novice when it comes to PHP and stuff and have added too much content since first noticing the error to roll the whole site back!

Thanks in advance for any help you might offer :)

**Here's the error I get instead of the relevant reports (all other reports work fine):**

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_id() on array in /home/my-server/public_html/my-website/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/admin/reports/class-wc-report-stock.php:81 Stack trace: #0 /home/my-server/public_html/my-website/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php(1254): WC_Report_Stock->column_default(Object(stdClass), 'product') #1 /home/my-server/public_html/my-website/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php(1192): WP_List_Table->single_row_columns(Object(stdClass)) #2 /home/my-server/public_html/my-website/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php(1180): WP_List_Table->single_row(Object(stdClass)) #3 /home/my-server/public_html/my-website/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php(1165): WP_List_Table->display_rows() #4 /home/my-server/public_html/my-website/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php(1097): WP_List_Table->display_rows_or_placeholder() #5 /home/my-server/public_html/my-website/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/admin/reports/class-wc-report-stock.php(68): WP_List_Table->display() #6 /home/my-server/publ in /home/my-server/public_html/my-website/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/admin/reports/class-wc-report-stock.php on line 81

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.  Note that error messages, while a bit confusing / jumbly looking, actually contain a _wealth_ of information.  If you focus on this part: `plugins/woocommerce/includes/admin/reports/class-wc-report-stock.php:81` - it tells you _exactly_ where the error is being thrown - the plugin as well the file and the specific line (81).  However, when you say you've "disabled all plugins" - I'm guessing you have NOT disabled this plugin, otherwise the error wouldn't happen.  To help solve the problem, you'd need to tell us _specifically_ what you were doing that "Broke" it.

Comment: Thanks for your response cale_b! Unfortunately, I've been spending seventeen hours a day on the site every day since the error occurred so have done far too much tweaking since to be able to pinpoint it... I'm a little confused though; isn't that file an integral part of Woocommerce? If so, I'm not sure how to disable only that part? Forgive my ignorance, just starting to seriously look at PHP!

Comment: ...if that file's broken somehow, could I not just replace it with a fresh copy, or would this have negative knock-on effects?

Comment: It's not necessarily _that file_ that's broken.  It could be something else that's "feeding" that file (calling a function in that file) with bad information.  Without knowing what that line of code is, and what function that line of code is within, it's very difficult to sort out what is causing the problem.  HOWEVER, if we knew the name of the function that line 81 is within, then we could start looking at what is calling that function, and what might be broken.

Comment: Find `if ( ! $product || $product->get_id() !== $item->id ) {`

 and changed to

`if ( ! $product || is_array($product) || $product->get_id() !== $item->id ) {`

Comment: @cale_b - Your explanation is much appreciated! Line 81 seems to be within "public function column_default( $item, $column_name ) {" - i tried searching all my code snippets for "column_default" but nothing showed up...should I download all the files and perhaps search that way instead? If not I shall go ask my PHP friends IRL! :) Thanks again for bothering to help me, I'm slowly starting to realise I should have been learning PHP all these years!

Comment: @ShashankSharma - Thanks for chiming in, I tried the replacement as you suggested but nothing seemed to change (cleared cache, etc. too)...